# deterministic finite-state automaton for the language L = {w ∈ {0, 1} ∗ | w does not start with 01 and does not end with 10}.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

[image: enter [![enter image description here]

So I think this is correct but wanted to get a second opinion, but wasn't sure how to test it rather than coming up with strings. Also, it seems a bit complicated, and I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

[image]

Comment: Is the empty word in $L$?

Comment: Yes! I forgot about that, so besides changing the entry node to accept, is it fine?

Comment: Is the word $100$ in $L$? Why does the rightmost state lack successors?

Comment: You are right, I can't believe I missed those let me fix it and edit

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I've added a second attempt

Comment: What about $011$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I've updated again, sorry to keep bothering especially when it fails so fast!

Comment: You need $6$ states, and the loop back to the initial state cannot be right, if you think about it: you cannot distinguish $01$ from $0001$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Updated once, more! I won't bother you again if this one is wrong, I'll spend some time writing down a bunch of test cases!

Comment: It looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need six states, representing the following situations:

1. No symbols yet read.
2. One symbol read which is a $0$.
3. The first two symbols are $01$. [Fail]
4. The last symbol is a $1$.
5. The last two symbols are $00$.
6. The last two symbols are $10$. [Fail]

See if you can figure out what the transitions are.

Comment: I've added a second attempt, and I think I followed your suggestions